# Unique solution to a second order IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm stuck on how to approach this question, any tips/solutions would be amazing.

Consider the initial value problem
$$\frac{d^2\mathbf{x}}{dt^2}=-\frac{GM}{r^3}\mathbf{x}$$
with $\mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf{x}_0$ and $\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}(0)=\mathbf{v}_0$. For which values of $\mathbf{x}_0$ and $\mathbf{v}_0$ does this problem have a unique solution $\mathbf{x}(t)$ for sufficiently small $t$?

Note that $r=|\mathbf{x}|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ and $G$ and $M$ are constants.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are $G,M$, and $r$ constant or do they depend on $t$ or $x$? There is a standard trick to reduce the order of an ordinary differential equation by considering $y(t)=(x(t),x'(t))$. You can then apply the theory of vector-valued first order differential equations.

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to add that $r=|\mathbf{x}|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$. $G,M$ are constants.

Comment: Apart from starting in the singularity at the origin, local solutions always do exist for the gravitational equation. The solutions that are not on a direct linear course to the singularity will even exist for all times in both directions. Where do you feel a trap could be?